# Refreshing JList in GUI on button event

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've looked online about how to update a `JList` after adding to its model. Some say that it does it automatically, others say you have to manually do it. I've tried both, and I haven't had much success. I'm trying to just update the model with the `addElement` method, and it goes through. I've walked through the code and everything is passed correctly. The GUI doesn't refresh.

```
package com.user.tutorial;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;

import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.List;

public class Window {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Window window = new Window();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
public Window() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame. This is where Window Builder
 * will generate its code.
 */
public void addTo(JPanel displayPanel, Component contentToAdd)
{
    displayPanel.add(contentToAdd);
}

public void initialize() {

    Dimension sidePanelSize = new Dimension(180, 540);

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 480, 540);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenuItem mntmLoad = new JMenuItem("Load");
    mnFile.add(mntmLoad);

    JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
    mnFile.add(mntmSave);

    JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    mnFile.add(mntmExit);

    final JPanel itemPanel = new JPanel();
    itemPanel.setPreferredSize(sidePanelSize);
    itemPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    itemPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
    for (String items : new String [] {"Case", "Motherboard", "CPU", "GPU", "PSU", "RAM", "HDD"})
        model.addElement(items);

    final JList<String> itemList = new JList<>();
    itemList.setModel(model);

    itemList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    itemList.setFont(new Font("SegoeUI", Font.BOLD, 11));
    itemPanel.add(itemList, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.getContentPane().add(itemPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    final JList<String> addToList = new JList<>(new DefaultListModel<String>());

    JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonList = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    buttonList.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonList, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    buttonContainer.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    buttonContainer.setBackground(new Color(238, 238, 238));

    final JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
    displayPanel.setPreferredSize(sidePanelSize);
    displayPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);    

             // Right here is where I do the button action. The `displayModel` is the model of the `JList` I'm updating.

        JButton addButton = new JButton(">>");
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                List<String> selected = itemList.getSelectedValuesList();
                DefaultListModel<String> displayModel = (DefaultListModel<String>) addToList.getModel();

                for (String item: selected) {
                    displayModel.addElement(item);
                }
            }
        });
        buttonList.add(addButton);


        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("<<");
        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        buttonList.add(deleteButton);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        buttonContainer.add(buttonList, c);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong. I've checked the documentation. I just guess I'm missing something simple. Thanks for the help.

Comment: All you need to do is update the `ListModel` and the `JList` will repaint itself. If it doesn't work then you 1) didn't update the model 2) the model isn't added to a JList, or 3) the JList is not visible on the Gui. Did you add a display statement to make sure the `addElement(...)` method is invoked? Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for a working example. If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr sorry about that I edited that everything is there. I just left out the imports and etc. Everything seems to be there, but it wont display on the GUI. Everything seems to be passed but there isn't a change to the GUI.

Comment: Why is addToList a local variable in initialize()?  Seems like it should be an instance variable so you can access it from other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Everything seems to be passed but there isn't a change to the GUI.

Did you read point "3" of my suggestion of possible problems?

Answer (score 0):

@camickr , @FredK thanks for the help. The suggestions helped a lot. It turns out that at some point when changing something, I deleted the assignment of the JList to that particular panel. It was updating, but It was never assigned to the panel.